# Python Search for a specific value in a nested dictionary and get one dictionary including the value

Tags: python, dictionary, validation, extract

I am trying to get a dictionary that includes a specific value from nested dictionaries.

My multiple dictionaries look like this:

```
MyDto = [{'app' : 'chrome',
'id': 'adetwt',
'name': 'John',
'selection': {'food':1324, 'var1': 2039, 'var2': 2126, 'var3': 0}},
{'app' : 'chrome',
'id': 'asdfb',
'name': 'Sam',
'selection': {'food':1324, 'var1': 2011, 'var2': 2123, 'var3': 0}},
{'app' : 'chrome',
'id': 'sfsf',
'name': 'Mary',
'selection': {'food':1324, 'var1': 2013, 'var2': 2111, 'var3': 0}}]
```

I want to only get a dictionary with a specific value.
For example, in this example,

```
if MyDto['id'] = 'sfsf'
```

The result I want to get is

```
extracted_dict = {'app' : 'chrome',
'id': 'sfsf',
'name': 'Mary',
'selection': {'food':1324, 'var1': 2013, 'var2': 2111, 'var3': 0}
```

Is there a way to get a dictionary based on a specific value it includes? Sorry if this is too basic question :( Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with something like:

```
key,value = 'id','sfsf'
dictList = [ myDict for myDict in MyDto if myDict.get(key) == value ]
print(dictList)
```

output

```
[{'app': 'chrome', 'id': 'sfsf', 'name': 'Mary', 'selection': {'food': 1324, 'var1': 2013, 'var2': 2111, 'var3': 0}}]
```

The list comprehension obviously produces a list of dicts and not a single dict.
With this list comprehension you scan all the dicts in your `MyDto`, and select only the ones which contain the pair key/value you chose.
It also works if the key is not present in any dictionary in `MyDto`, that is it avoids a `KeyError` exception and produces and empty list.

If you are sure that at most only one dict with key/value is contained in the list:

```
def getByKeyAndValue(dictList, key, value):
        for myDict in dictList:
            if myDict.get(key) == value:
                return myDict
        return {}

extracted_dict = getByKeyAndValue(MyDto, 'id', 'sfsf')
```

This function scans your `MyDto` only until it finds the dict you want to extract. If it does not find the dict, it returns an empty dict.

Comment: Yes, both work well. As only one dict is with the key/value in the list, I used the second function. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hello @vaeVictis, I have similar issue but in my case I want to return dictionary if value matches the substring. I tried `dictList = [ myDict for myDict in MyDto if myDict.get(key) in value ]`. But this doesn't work. Can you please let me know what should I use?

Comment: @Preeti I am not going to answer here. Please, create a specific thread and be clear about your needs and your try. Then, please put the link here and I will support there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over items and get the right dict as below:

```
MyDto = [
    {'app': 'chrome',
     'id': 'adetwt',
     'name': 'John',
     'selection': {'food': 1324, 'var1': 2039, 'var2': 2126, 'var3': 0}},
    {'app': 'chrome',
     'id': 'asdfb',
     'name': 'Sam',
     'selection': {'food': 1324, 'var1': 2011, 'var2': 2123, 'var3': 0}},
    {'app': 'chrome',
     'id': 'sfsf',
     'name': 'Mary',
     'selection': {'food': 1324, 'var1': 2013, 'var2': 2111, 'var3': 0}}
]


def get_by_id(id: str):
    for dict_ in MyDto:
        if dict_['id'] == id:
            return dict_['selection']


print(get_by_id('sfsf'))
```

Comment: he wants to retrieve all the dict, not the `dict_[selection]`

Answer (score -1):

gotta love list comprehension:

```
[d for d in MyDto if d['id'] == 'sfsf']
```